# How can I extract the full datetime from a Beautifulsoup ResultSet?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the date and time of an Instagram post using selenium and beautifulsoup. I'm not sure how to extract the `datetime` element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/B5LeHK2h4p0/')

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

dateTime= soup.select('time._1o9PC.Nzb55')
```

If I print `dateTime` this is what I get:

```
[<time class="_1o9PC Nzb55" datetime="2019-11-22T19:20:29.000Z" title="Nov 22, 2019">November 22, 2019</time>]
```

also, `type(dateTime)` yields:

```
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
```

How can I extract `2019-11-22T19:20:29.000Z` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dateTime = soup.select('time._1o9PC.Nzb55' )[0]['datetime']
```

`[0]` To extract it from the list, and than access the `datetime` tag.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been almost 2 hours trying to understand how to handle these objects (ResultSets)